# How to change the toolbar SearchView Underline color to GRAY

Tags: android, xml, toolbar, android-toolbar, searchview

I am trying to change the underline color of search view when we expand the search bar`

```
    SearchView.SearchAutoComplete autoCompleteTextView = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    autoCompleteTextView.setCursorVisible(true);
    autoCompleteTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.textcolor_light_gray));
    autoCompleteTextView.setHintTextColor(autoCompleteTextView.getTextColors().withAlpha(255));
    autoCompleteTextView.setTextSize(16);

    View searchplate = (View)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    searchplate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.autocomplete_bg);
```

Here i used the theme to change the color also

```
 <style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
    <item name="queryBackground">@color/darkgray</item>

</style>
```

but nothing working for me. any one help me pls...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally i got the solution..

```
    View searchplate = (View)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    searchplate.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.DKGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: Can we do the same via xml?
themes or styles?

Comment: NO. i tried with themes or styles only.but it didn't work.so only i was added with color filter

Comment: @sree getBackground() returns null

Comment: @ArturA, we need to set the background before using getBackground(). Here i used searchplate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.autocomplete_bg);

Comment: Had to add PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP to discard original base color of the underline and use the new one.

Answer (score 4):

You can change it also by xml:

```
<item name="android:queryBackground">...</item>
```

I guess you forgot `android:` prefix

Answer (score 0):

Below sample worked work me, I hope it works for you too.

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_searchview"
    android:queryBackground="@drawable/bg_searchview_query"/>
```

**android:queryBackground="@drawable/bg_searchview_query"**

in drawable, create `.xml` file **bg_searchview** for background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <padding
        android:top="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="0.3dp"
        android:color="#797979" />
</shape>
```

in drawable, create a .xml file **bg_searchview_query** for queryBackground

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```